# Finding "sub-palindromes" 2: subsequences.

Tags: code-golf, palindrome, subsequence

The same task as [Finding "sub-palindromes"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183/finding-sub-palindromes) but instead of finding substrings you must find **subsequences** that are **not substrings**.

eg1:

```
input: "12131331"
output: 
"11", "33", "111", "121", "131", "313", "333", "1111", "1331", "11311", "13331"
or 
"11", "33", "111", "333", "1111", "11311", "13331"
```

eg2:

```
input: "3333"
output: 
"33", "333"
or
(null)
```

- Input is a string of printable ascii characters.
- Output is a list of *unique* strings.
- If a subsequence also appears as a substring it may be omitted.
- Shortest code wins.

Comment: It *may* be omitted or it *must* be omitted? Header and details don't match.

Comment: @J B: *may* be omitted. Where is the mismatch?

Comment: @Eelvex "subsequences that are not substrings".  That part reads like substrings aren't allowed.

Comment: @J-B: Substrings are **not** allowed. What you *may* or *may not* omit is a **subsequence** that **also** appears as a substring. Take a look at the examples: "1331" is a *subsequence* "12 **13** 13 **31** " but *also* a substring "1213 **1331** " so you may omit it.

Comment: @Eelvex: look at it this way.  The example output includes "1331".  But "1331" is a substring.  Thus I don't understand why it's there, given that substrings are not allowed.

Comment: @J-B: Look at it this way: use sequence indexes instead of values. The sequence I'm referring to is "2367" while the sequence you are referring to is "4567". They are completely different but *happen* to have the same *value* so you may omit the *sequence* if it is easier to code it that way.

Comment: @J-B: When I say "subsequences that are not substrings" I mean the set of subsequences that does not include the subset of substrings. i.e. the relative complement of subsequences to substrings. I think the misunderstanding is that it might seem I mean the list of subsequences that is not common with the list of substrings.

Comment: @J-B: btw, you'are not allowed to print "3333" in the second example because there is no such subsequence; only a substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 39 characters

```
:^1/[""]\{`{1$\+}+%}/.&{..-1%=^@?0<&},`
```

Examples:

```
> "12131331"
["11" "333" "111" "13331" "13131" "1111" "11311"]

> "3333"
[]
```

Basic blocks of the code:

```
# Save input in variable
:^

# Build all possible subsequences of the input
1/[""]\{`{1$\+}+%}/

# Filter unique ones
.&

# Filter relevant palindromes
{.
  .-1%=   # check if palindrome
  ^@?0<   # check if sequence is no substring
  &       # and operation on both
},

# Format output
`
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (119)

```
import Data.List
main=interact f
f a=show.nub.filter(\x->(not$isInfixOf a x)&&x==reverse x&&length x>1)$subsequences a
```

Isn't too difficult with a builtin `subsequences` and `nub`... :)

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript (95)

```
);.{{(\a\:x;.{[x]\+}%+}:b;{.!{[$]}{b}if}:a;.a{..-1%=&},\{,}{(;}/{{,}{);}/}%{+}*-.&{`}%", "*}and
```

I haven't really tried to golf this further, it's just a combination of left overs.

The question is inconsistent. My program prints all palindromic subsequences that are not substrings. Hope this is OK.

Example 1:

```
echo "12131331" | ruby golfscript.rb subseq_not_substr.gs
"11", "111", "13331", "13131", "1111", "11311"
```

Example 2:

```
echo "3333" | ruby golfscript.rb subseq_not_substr.gs
```

Empty String Example:

```
echo "" | ruby golfscript.rb subseq_not_substr.gs
```

With uglier output formatting, eg `[11 111 13331 13131 1111 11311]`, it could be made a bit shorter.

Comment: Any way of formatting the output list is ok. Make it shorter :)