# Find the Longest Palindrome in a String by Removing Characters

Tags: code-golf, palindrome

**Problem:** Remove characters from strings to make the longest (character length) palindrome possible. The first line gives an integer value of the number of strings to test. Each subsequent line is a string to test.

**Example Input:**

```
3 // Number of lines to test
GGABZXVYCCDBA
ABGBAD
ABC
```

**Example Output:**

```
ABCCBA
ABGBA
B
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Would `A` and `C` also be acceptable answers for the last test?

Comment: Please give an objective winning criterion.

Comment: From your example I infer that you ask for a complete program which can process multiple strings as input. The problem specification only asks for a single string - can you please clarify. Also does *largest* means *longest/most characters*?

Comment: Why is this tagged "Java"?

Comment: related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/862/finding-sub-palindromes-2-subsequences

Comment: seems close enough to be duplicate

Comment: @Howard Basically the same question. This one asks for the longest one, and that one asks for all of them. You could just take the longest and then you would have an answer to this question. Voted to close as duplicate

Comment: @shiona A and C would also be acceptable answers for the last test. If there is a tie for the largest palindrome, pick any one of them.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow this is not a duplicate. This one requires that you *remove characters to make the palindrome.

Comment: @Connor That one does too. "Subsequence" means any sequence you can get by removing 1 or more characters.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Oh. I didn't know my bad. I'm still pretty new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Java (not exactly short hah)...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/pal.dat"));

        int q = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        for (int z = 0; z < q; z++) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();

            int max = 0;
            String maxP = "";

            for (int k = 0; k < line.length(); k++) {

                String p = calc(line.substring(k));

                if (p.length() > max) {
                    max = p.length();
                    maxP = p;
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Max Palindrome: " + maxP);

        }

    }

    public static String calc(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return "";
        if (s.length() == 1 || (s.length() == 2 && s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(1)))
            return s.charAt(0) + "";
        if (s.length() == 2)
            return s;

        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

        boolean match = false;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[0]) {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        int max = 0;
        String maxPalin = "";
        for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
            String p = calc(s.substring(k, i));
            if (p.length() > max) {
                max = p.length();
                maxPalin = p;
            }
        }

        if (match)
            return arr[0] + maxPalin + arr[0];
        return maxPalin;

    }

}
```