# Length of the Longest Palindromic Substring

Tags: code-golf, string, palindrome

A [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) is a string which is the same when read forwards and backwards. For example "racecar" is a palindrome, but "Racecar" is not. A [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) is a contiguous set of characters in a larger string. Your task is to write a program or method which takes a string or character array as input and outputs the length of the longest substring of that string which is a palindrome.

**Examples**

Input

```
banana
```

Ouput

```
5
```

This is because "anana" is a 5 character substring of "banana"

Input

```
abracadabra
```

Output

```
3
```

This is because both "aca" and "ada" are 3 characters.

Input

```
True
```

Output

```
1
```

This string has no palindromes that are more than 1 character.

If the input is the empty string the output must be 0.

This is code-golf so the shortest submission in any language wins.

Note: There have been slight variations of this question in the past, which have all had wording issues or been asking a variation of this question. You can see these:

[Find the Longest Palindrome in a String by Removing Characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19381/find-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-string-by-removing-characters)

[Longest reverse palindromic DNA substring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42184/longest-reverse-palindromic-dna-substring)

[How do I find the longest palindrome in a string?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16327/how-do-i-find-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-string)

[Finding "sub-palindromes".](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183/finding-sub-palindromes) - The purpose of this challenge is to print *all* palindromic substring, rather than the length of the longest. As such many of the answers to this question do not have close analogues.

Comment: [Related, borderline dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/183/42963). My vote is a hammer, though, so I won't vote as yet.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16327/how-do-i-find-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-string is another, but it's not really another.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn only the size of it. After all the longest palindrome might not be unique.

Comment: Which are the valid input characters ?

Comment: @TonHospel The original idea was that it would just be what ever the string type supports. Did you have something in mind?

Comment: The linked challenge is asking for _unique_ sub-palindromes. There is no such constraint here, so converting these answers is likely to be sub-optimal. (This still is a borderline dupe, though.)

Comment: @Bijan I usually golf this kind of thing using regexes. And if I substitute a string into a regex it's important to know if the characters can be regex metacharacters (like `.`, `+`, `*` etc) because just using them as is will cause errors. There is also the issue of spaces and newlines and how they are handled in I/O. Languages like `C` might worry about `\0` etc.

Comment: Given that most answers there can be ported here with "Length Each Max" appended (and it looks like that's a common approach), I think it can be considered a dupe.

Comment: @user202729 At least in perl it's not that easy since perl doesn't have a cheap `max` or `sort` so it's a bit different (not by much though, since I did find a close workaround). The simple `map length and max` is mostly for the golfing languages I think

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
{s.↔}ᶠlᵐ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7pY71HblNqH2xbkPNw64VFP5///SkmJeUCo9D8KAA)

#### Explanation

```
{   }ᶠ       Find all…
 s.            …substrings of the input…
  .↔           …which are their own reverse
      lᵐ     Map length
        ⌉    Max
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) (pointing out that `Þ` is stable and thus works instead of `Ðf`).

```
ẆŒḂÞṪL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrajkx7uaDo87@HOVT7///9PTCpKTE5MAVEA)

#### How?

```
ẆŒḂÞṪL – Full program.

Ẇ      – All contiguous non-empty subsequences.
   Þ   – Stable sort by...
 ŒḂ    – 1 if the element is palindrome, 0 otherwise.
    Ṫ  – Get the last element.
     L – And take its length.
```

Note that the substrings are ordered by length, in Jelly.

Comment: Since Jelly's sort is stable, you should be able to replace `Ðf` with `Þ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
le_I#.:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyc13lNZz@r/f6XEpKLE5MQUEKUEAA)

#### How?

```
le_I#.: – Full program.

     .: – All contiguous non-empty subsequences.
    #   – Keep those...
  _I    – That are invariant under reversal.
 e      – Get the last element.
l       – And take its length.
```

Note that the substrings are ordered by length, in Pyth.

Comment: Do we know the last element is the longest (i.e. are the subsequences ordered by length)?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, in Pyth the substrings are ordered by length.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ŒʒÂQ}€gM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6KRTkw43BdY@alqT7vv/f1JiHhAWg0kA)

Comment: Was just about to post this :)

Comment: @Emigna I know there was a 3-byter for "filter list to contain only palindromes"... Can't remember though.

Comment: Don't think I know a 3-byter for that. I was hoping that `à` would work, but unfortunately it goes alphabetically and not by length when used on strings.

Comment: @Emigna I was thinking `ŒéR` then "find first palindrome", or `Œé` and find last palindrome, cant seem to do that in 4 or less though.

Comment: Yeah, using `é` also ends up at 8 bytes. I feel like it is impossible to do the "outside" code in less than 4 and I don't see a way to do the filtering in less than 4 either. Other methods I've tried all end up at 8 or 9 as well. Unless I'm missing something, this feels optimal.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 163 bytes

```java
s->{int r=0,l=s.length(),i=0,j,T;for(String t;i<l;i++)for(j=i;++j<=l;r=t.contains(new StringBuffer(t).reverse())&(T=t.length())>r?T:r)t=s.substring(i,j);return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZG9bsMgFIX3PMVVhgpkx@pc4lTq3gyNt6oDxjiBEmxdrl1VkZ/dxT8ZqwgQ4vBdzgGs7OWuabW31feonAwB3qXxtw2A8aSxlkrDcVrOAih2IjT@DIGLKA5xxB5IklFwBA85jGF3uE0s5s@py0PmtD/ThfHURMGmhagbvB9DwuydMEnCJ9HmRiSJ3edOYE6ZajzFMIF5/QNLwVtX1xoZ8Qx1rzFoxvkTKyJ8d@EHfC1ekFN0Dl0Z5jJmUssFaurQA4phFEvwtitdDL7m7xtTwTU6ruk@vyRfrn76DaSvWdNR1sYdcp75TLFtKX1sWz4/xv@YLFEqWU3TQ7bATj@EPuK3KIkPuRUYNsP4Bw)

```java
s->{                 // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0,           //  Result-String, starting empty
      l=s.length(),  //  The length of the input-String
      i=0,j,         //  Index-integers
      T;             //  Temp integer
  for(String t;      //  Temp String
      i<l;i++)       //  Loop `i` over the String
    for(j=i;++j<=l;  //   Inner loop `j` over the String
        r=           //     After every iteration, set the result to:
          t.contains(new StringBuffer(t).reverse())
                     //      If the temp-String is a palindrome,
          &(T=t.length())>r?
                     //      and the length of the substring is larger than the result
           T         //       Set this length as the new result
          :          //      Else:
           r)        //       Keep the result the same
      t=s.substring(i,j);
                     //    Set the temp String to the substring from index `i` to `j`
  return r;}         //  Return the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
L►LfS=↔Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@fRtF0@acG2j9qmBP7//18pMakoMTkxBUQpAQA)

#### How?

```
L►LfS=↔Q – Full program.

       Q – All contiguous non-empty subsequences.
   f     – Keep those...
    S=   – That are equal to themselves when...
      ↔  – Reversed.
 ►L      – Get the maximum element, sorted by length.
L        – Take its length.
```

Alternative: `▲mLfS=↔Q`. Note that the substrings are **not** ordered by length, in Husk.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 42 bytes

```
Lv`(.)*.?(?<-1>\1)*(?(1)(?!))
N$^`
$.&
\G.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N@nLEFDT1NLz17D3kbX0C7GUFNLw17DUFPDXlFTk8tPJS6BS0VPjSvGXe///6TEPCDkSkwqSkxOTAFRXCVFpakA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
Lv`(.)*.?(?<-1>\1)*(?(1)(?!))
```

For each character in the string, find the longest palindrome that starts at that point.

```
N$^`
$.&
```

Sort the found palindromes in reverse order of length.

```
\G.
```

Count the length of the first (i.e. longest) palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:len(s)if s==s[::-1]else max(f(s[1:]),f(s[:-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYmxCoAgFEX3vkKcfFBDtAn@RVs0PEspMAufQX39y5Yg7nLuOcedlz12zN4E3OyMgnRwURGsXpAxNGjdtKML5MSGl/KKhlaPUL/wFgA@0hpzKdJiLJMA1afQ4oQz2vTXfTrdT5TDDw)

Comment: Nice answer, but you shouldn't answer so quickly :P I'd advise waiting it a week or so, however you can keep the answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
[:>./@,#\(#*]-:|.)\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63s9PQddJRjNJS1YnWtavQ0Y2L/a3IpcKUmZ@QrpCmo5yWCoDqcn5hUlJicmAKiEIIhRaWp6v8B)